# Saving a list of plots by their names()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a list of plots that I've created.

```
library(ggplot2)
plots <- list()
plots$a <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
plots$b <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed)) + geom_histogram()
plots$c <- ggplot(cars, aes(dist)) + geom_histogram()
```

Now, I would like to save all of these, labelling each with their respective names(plots) element.

```
lapply(plots, 
       function(x) { 
         ggsave(filename=paste(...,".jpeg",sep=""), plot=x)
         dev.off()
         }
       )
```

What would I replace "..." with such that in my working directory the plots were saved as:

```
a.jpeg
b.jpeg
c.jpeg
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

probably you need to pass the names of list:

```
lapply(names(plots), 
  function(x)ggsave(filename=paste(x,".jpeg",sep=""), plot=plots[[x]]))
```

Comment: +1 and accept for sheer simplicity. It's a head slapping moment for me. Thanks Koshke!

Answer (score 1):

[@kohske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314020/kohske)'s answer is sensational! Below is the `purrr 0.3.4` version for those who may prefer working within `tidyverse`. Also, a temporary directory is created to hold the plots since `ggsave` defaults to saving to the working directory.

```
map(names(plots), function(.x) {
    ggsave(
        path = "tmp/",
        filename = paste0(.x, ".png"),
        plot = plots[[.x]]
        )
    })
```