# r - Printing plots from list returns quosure error

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, plot, quosure

I have generated a series of plots using `ggplot` and `lapply`, like so:

```
makeplot <- function(data){

    require(ggplot2)
    require(dplyr)

    ggplot(data,aes(x=num,y=cat3, fill=cat3)) +
    facet_wrap(~cat2)
    # etc...
}

plot_list <- lapply(split(data, interaction(data[,c("province","cat1")]), drop = TRUE), makeplot)
```

I am using a large data frame that could be simplified to:

```
data <- data.frame(
    province = sample(c("1","2","3","4")),
    cat1 = sample(c("health","education","banks","etc")),
    cat2 = sample(c("winter","spring","summer","fall")),
    cat3 = sample(c("1 hour","2 hours","4 hours","8 hours")),
    Y = sample(1:100))
```

This generates a list of plots like so:

[Plot list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz8VO.png)

I am attempting to print or `ggsave` out this list, as per here: [Saving plots within lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241954/saving-plots-within-lapply).

However, all attempts to export/print the resulting plots, whether with an `lapply` loop or a simple `print` statement return the following error.

```
lapply(plot_list,print)

Error: `quo` must be a quosure
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

I'm afraid the R documentation on quosures didn't yield any helpful insights. I'm not a developer and don't really understand most of the documentation. Can anyone help me out?

I originally posted this without much of the complex `lapply` filtering happening earlier, as it seemed a distracting irrelevance. I'm providing that now in case it's helpful. For reference, the actual data frame `head` looks like:

```
~season,                          ~fac_type,         ~trav_cat,       ~avg_pc_pop,                                             ~loop,
"Monsoon season",       "All financial institutions", "0 to 30 minutes",  0.41395948733655,       "Monsoon season All financial institutions",
"Normal season",            "All health facilities", "0 to 30 minutes", 0.426855030030894,            "Monsoon season All health facilities",
"Other season",                    "All hospitals", "1 to 2 hours", 0.301967752836744,                    "Monsoon season All hospitals",
"Monsoon season", "Commercial and development banks", "4 to 8 hours", 0.385783483483483, "Monsoon season Commercial and development banks",
"Normal season",            "District Headquarters", "16 to 32 hours", 0.270673828371869,            "Monsoon season District Headquarters",
"Other season",             "Government hospitals", "1 to 2 hours", 0.263825993199371,             "Monsoon season Government hospitals"
```

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Hi Tung, sure. The data is a bit complicated but I'll do my best.

Comment: In the mean time, check these related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902877/786542 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045111/786542

Comment: OK thanks Tung. Edits made, let me know if I can refine further. I'm still new to R SO and understand reproducible example making is an acquired skill

Comment: I'm not reproducing your error with your example code and data (although I had to use `x = Y` instead of `x = num` since `num` wasn't in `data`). Does the example code give the error for you?

Comment: @aosmith On checking I was able to do this with my example code and data, although both closely resembles the original code and data. In the end I had to use a different method to get what I wanted.