# R: Producing several barcharts with ggplot2 and lapply: how to insert the subtitles according to a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

My aim is to produce and save several bar plots with `lapply` and `ggplot2`. For this Purpose, I have created a list out of my data. Now everything works fine apart from the subtitles: I would like to insert the names of the elements of my list into the graphs. So far I could only insert the name of the first element.

I have found another post, which helped me a lot to get so far. I'm new here, so I hope I'm posting this question in the right way (I haven't found an option to relate to this other post).

I adapted this Code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241954/saving-plots-within-lapply)
because I have a follow-up question to the case provided there.

```r
###creating some random data:

df <- data.frame(value = floor(runif(20,min=0,max=30)), 
                 Intervall = paste("Intervall",rep(1:10,2)), type = rep(c("a", "b")))

list1 <- split(df, df$type)

###producing plots with lapply and ggplot

plots <- lapply(list1, function(x) {
                       ggplot(x, aes(Intervall, value)) + 
                        geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
                        labs(title="Intervalle", subtitle =names(list1))})
lapply(names(plots), 
       function(x) ggsave(filename=paste(x,".emf",sep=""), plot=plots[[x]]))
```

The elements of my list are called `a` and `b`. Now the first graph should have the subtitle `"a"`, and the second graph the subtitle `"b"`.

How can I do so? (also how can I first see my plots in the console before saving them?)

With `names(list1)` `"a"` becomes the subtitle for both graphs…

Comment: The issue is with `subtitle = names(list1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to the second command.  It comes from the creation of 'plots'.  In the `subtitle`, we are passing the whole `names(list1)` instead of corresponding elements.  If we loop through the `names` of 'list1', it becomes easier to get the corresponding name for each list element, also, the `list` can be subsetted based on the same names

```
plots <- lapply(names(list1), function(nm) {
                       ggplot(list1[[nm]], aes(Intervall, value)) + 
                        geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
                        labs(title="Intervalle", subtitle =nm)})
names(plots) <- names(list1)
```

Now, we use the same command as in the OP (changed the `.emf` to `.png`

```
lapply(names(plots), function(nm) ggsave(filename =
       paste(path, nm, ".png", sep=""), plot = plots[[nm]]))
```

-plots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answert:)!it works perfectly well apart from the part with the path. Instead of "path" I used "S/Folder_a/bins". Like this, my graphs werent saved at all. Its not that bad, since I can also just define a different working directory, but still it could be handy. I also tried to create an object called "path" with file.path, which didnt work either.

Comment: @CEc  Yes, I meant `path` to be changed.  I should have mentioned.  It is a custom path for you.  I didn't want to save my file in my current working directory.  I would use `"S/Folder_a/bins/"` notice the last `/`

Comment: Oh of course! Missed the last "/". thanks again:):)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `by` in place of `split` + `lapply` and use *type* in *subtitle* and *filename* arguments.

```
# NAMED LIST OF PLOTS
plots <- by(df, df$type, function(sub) {
            p <- ggplot(sub, aes(Intervall, value)) + 
                  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
                  labs(title="Intervalle", subtitle = sub$type[1])

            ggsave(filename=paste0(sub$type[1],".emf"), plot=p)

            return(p)
         })
```

Comment: Thank you :):)!This also worked out, Im very happy to have gotten two really helpful answers in such a short time:)!