# Set resolution in ggsave: how can I save pngs with set resolution, height and width?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, png, lapply

I have a code which produces several bar plots with `lapply`. In this code I want to automatically specify units, width, height and resolution for my pngs with `ggsave` (I need to adjust the proportions of the pictures I produce, because some weeks ago I already produced hundreds of emf-pictures and came to the conclusion that png is the better format).

My question is related to a former post of mine ([R: Producing several barcharts with ggplot2 and lapply: how to insert the subtitles according to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717569/r-producing-several-barcharts-with-ggplot2-and-lapply-how-to-insert-the-subtit)), but this post here is more about pngs.

If I don't use lapply and make my bar plot by bar plot, this works perfectly fine:
First I set my working Directory, then I specify my png, and I close the device again:

```
png(filename="190709_bp_DA_MQ.png",units = "in",width=10, height=7,res = 120)
```

But with `lapply` and `ggplot` (`ggsave` and `paste`) it does not work anymore. I get the following Error

> Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
> formal argument "res" matched by multiple actual arguments

```r
###producing some random data
df <- data.frame(
  value = floor(runif(20,min=0,max=30)),
  Intervall = paste("Intervall",rep(1:10,2)), 
  type = rep(c("a", "b"))
)

list1 <- split(df, df$type)

###producing plots with lapply and ggplot
path <- ("S:/")
plots <- lapply(names(list1), function(nm) {
  ggplot(list1[[nm]], aes(Intervall, value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    labs(title = "Intervalle", subtitle = nm)
})
names(plots) <- names(list1)

plots

#saving as pngs
lapply(names(plots), function(nm) { 
  ggsave(filename = paste(path, nm, ".png", sep = ""), 
         width = 10, height = 7, plot = plots[[nm]])
})


#If I only specify width and height, the code works. 

#But: I want to have the units in Inches and also add the resolution. if I add #units and resolution, the code doesnt work anymore. 

lapply(names(plots), function(nm) {
  ggsave(filename = paste(path,nm, ".png", sep = ""), 
         units = "in", width = 10, height = 7, res = 120, plot = plots[[nm]])
})
```

Comment: The resolution parameter of `ggsave` is `dpi` not `res`. Also, what exactly does "the code doesnt work"  mean?

Comment: the code not working means, I guess, that the error mentioned in the question is returned ;-) But this should disappear with using `dpi`

Comment: the error itself means, that there are several arguments specified in the function that can be matched by `res`. See 4th slide in here https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf

Comment: Oh ok, easy solution! many thanks to both of you, now it worked:)!