# Setting image resolution with ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found myself confused by ggsave not accepting the res argument.

```
ggplot()
ggsave("p.png", res = 300)
```

> Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
> formal argument "res" matched by multiple actual arguments

Luckily, user Roland's comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57144226/7941188) helped. I decided to ask a new question because editing the former to the core of the problem seemed more work.

A closer look into ?ggsave might have helped too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, and I find very confusingly, ggsave seems to have a different name for the "res" argument in `grDevices::<device>`

use `ggsave(dpi = ...)`, if you want to change `grDevices::<device>(res = ...)`